# How to specify multiple tiered trackers in magnet URI?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, deluge, magnet-links, qbittorrent

I know how to specify trackers in the [magnet URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#Address_tracker_.28tr.29). I need to use `&tr=[tracker address]`. But when I add it, all the specified trackers in the magnet link go into Tier-0. What should I do if I want to add 2 trackers in Tier-0 and then another 2 trackers in Tier-1?

> Trackers are placed in groups, or tiers, with a tracker randomly chosen from the top tier and tried, moving to the next tier if all the trackers in the top tier fail.

If you need more information about Tiers: [Multitracker on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Multitracker)

Eg: The following magnet-URI is the magnet URI of Ubuntu ISO and when I add this into a torrent client, all specified trackers go into Tier-0. I know that I can select a tracker and click "Down" to move it to the next Tier(ie, Tier-1) **but is there any way to specify these Tiers within the magnet URI itself?**

> magnet:?xt=urn:btih:D0F23C109D8662A3FE9338F75839AF8D57E5D4A9
>   &dn=Ubuntu+MATE+16.04.2+%5BMATE%5D%5Barmhf%5D%5Bimg.xz%5D%5BUzerus%5D
>   &tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce
>   &tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce
>   &tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce
>   &tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify in a magnet link, what tier a tracker is added to.

There is nothing in the BitTorrent protocol specification on how to do that.
So it's up to the implementer of a client to decide how to do it.

Deluge, as you have noticed, adds all trackers to tier-0.
Other clients, for example: µtorrent, adds every tracker in it's own, separate tier.

Comment: [Transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3341) supports [tr.0, tr.1 notation](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/changeset/13619). Here is some more info about this on [Deluge forum](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2716). Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: Yes, Transmission as well as other clients support the *tr.x* notation as a alias to *tr*, but afaik no client uses *x* to determine what tier a tracker is added to.